# Condicional de erro em C

Tags: c, variáveis

Quando eu mexia em Python me lembro que tinha como fazer um `if` caso alguma atribuição ou operação retornasse erro. Tipo assim

```
int v[]={1,2};
int v1;
if((v1=v)==ERRO)
    //faça isso;
```

Tem alguma coisa parecida assim em C?

Comment: Você quer dizer `if((v1==v) == ERRO)`, certo?

Comment: @MagicHat não, essa sintaxe não existe.

Comment: Nusssa brizei, num tem nem lógica...

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

C é uma linguagem dita estática, e de tipagem fraca, é o oposto de Python que é dinâmica e forte. Você não pode mudar um tipo da variável, como pode em Python, mas pode interpretar um dado como se fosse outro. É função do programador resolver isso no código.

Na verdade isso é um erro de programação, então você deve corrigi-lo e não tentar verificar no código se deu tudo certo. Se fosse outro exemplo pode ser que faria sentido fazer uma verificação, mas não nesse.

Pra ser sincero, eu acho esse código mesmo escrito em Python seria bem ruim e possivelmente um erro também, mas sei lá, pode ter um contexto que eu não sei.

Dependendo do compilador e da configuração isso dará erro de compilação, então nem precisa fazer isto.

Veja no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/I5yJVn) que nem compila.

Comment: Eu não lembro de sequer já ter visto isso em Python. Acredito que a sintaxe nem seja válida. Já no PHP é bem comum fazer, por exemplo,  `if ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {}`.